# Intermittent error serving a binary file with Clojure/Ring

Tags: clojure, ring

I am building an [event collector in Clojure](https://github.com/snowplow/snowplow/tree/feature/clj-collector/2-collectors/clojure-collector) for [Snowplow](http://snowplowanalytics.com/) (using Ring/Compojure) and am having some trouble serving a transparent pixel with Ring. This is my code for sending the pixel:

```
(ns snowplow.clojure-collector.responses
  (:import (org.apache.commons.codec.binary Base64)
           (java.io ByteArrayInputStream)))

(def pixel-bytes (Base64/decodeBase64 (.getBytes "R0lGODlhAQABAPAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw==")))
(def pixel (ByteArrayInputStream. pixel-bytes))

(defn send-pixel
   []
    {:status  200
     :headers {"Content-Type"   "image/gif"}
     :body    pixel})
```

When I start up my server, the first time I hit the path for `send-pixel`, the pixel is successfully delivered to my browser. But the second time - and every time afterwards - Ring sends no body (and content-length 0). Restart the server and it's the same pattern.

A few things it's not:

1. I have replicated this using `wget`, to confirm the intermittent-ness isn't a browser caching issue
2. I generated the `"R01GOD..."` base64 string at the command-line (`cat original.gif | base64`) so know there is no issue there
3. When the pixel is successfully sent, I have verified its contents are correct (`diff original.gif received-pixel.gif`)

I'm new to Clojure - my guess is there's some embarrassing dynamic gremlin in my code, but I need help spotting it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out the problem in the REPL shortly after posting:

```
user=> (import (org.apache.commons.codec.binary Base64) (java.io ByteArrayInputStream))
java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
user=> (def pixel-bytes (Base64/decodeBase64 (.getBytes "R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==")))
#'user/pixel-bytes
user=> (def pixel (ByteArrayInputStream. pixel-bytes))
#'user/pixel
user=> (slurp pixel-bytes)
"GIF89a!�\n,L;"
user=> (slurp pixel-bytes)
"GIF89a!�\n,L;"
user=> (slurp pixel)
"GIF89a!�\n,L;"
user=> (slurp pixel)
""
```

So basically the problem was that the `ByteArrayInputStream` was getting emptied after the first call. Mutable data structures!

I fixed the bug by generating a new `ByteArrayInputStream` for each response, with:

```
    :body    (ByteArrayInputStream. pixel-bytes)}))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `pixel` variable holds a stream. Once it has been read, there is no possibility to re-read it again.

Moreover, you do not need to deal with encoding issues. Ring serves static files as well. Just return:

```
(file-response "/path/to/pixel.gif")
```

It handles non-existing files as well. [See the docs](https://ring-clojure.github.io/ring/ring.util.response.html) also.